# IntelliJ run single Java file

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I am switching from Eclipse to IntelliJ, I'm trying to do something that's really simple to do in Eclipse.  This is probably a simple question, but I have a project in IntelliJ with a bunch of small .java class files with main classes.  These are just small practice programs I use for testing.  I am trying to right click one of the java class files, then 'Run'.  I'm expecting the class to run and see its output in the console - it looks like IntelliJ is instead trying to compile the entire project, including test classes.

How can I make IntelliJ just run the single class file without attempting to do a build of the entire project?

Also - In eclipse I am used to copying arguments to my main class into an input window when running a single java class.  Is there a way to do this in IntelliJ.

Thanks, I know I can do this from a terminal, but for my purposes it would be helpful to quickly run small java programs from an ide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the Default settings based on your needs, to either automatically build after each change or manually. This can be achieved by clicking on `File` -> `Other Settings` -> `Default Settings`. This is the popup window.

[image: Default Preferences]

To change the run configurations, you can follow below steps.

1. Goto `Run` tab at the top Toobar and click on `Edit Configurations`.
2. Click `+` icon and select `Application`. This opens a new popup window where you can add all your VM arguments & Program arguments similar to Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, Eclipse provides an input window that I don't have to click through popup menus and edit run configurations to get to - in order to enter arguments for main().  Does IntelliJ have an equivalent?

Comment: Yes. If you just run the main class, it will open a Run console where you can input the parameters. The method I gave is mainly for running with permanent parameters(like -Xmx, -DpropertyName etc )

Comment: Better answer below

Answer (score 9):

Another option could be useful and quick for you. Just write your class with `main` method you want to run, and then press a little green triangle either *behind your `main` method* or *behind your class name*:

[image]

After that you will be able to choose an option e.g., **Run**, **Debug** or **Run with Coverage**:

[image]

In this case IDEA will just run your class without building the entire project.

Comment: This builds the entire project. Not just single class.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the [not-so-new-now Scratch Files](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/09/intellij-idea-14-eap-138-2210-brings-scratch-files-and-better-mercurial-integration/); they're pretty good for trying simple things out and they are saved, so you can easily find them under recent files, or by name.

Answer (score 3):

Right click your class in the left side bar. Hit **Run**. But your class must have a main method.

[image]

Comment: Thats what I'm doing.  It attempts to build the entire project.  I just want to build and run a single class.

Answer (score 0):

Run->Edit Configurations and then change the class name to which you want run.

Example: Change `com.package.Main` to `com.package.Stopwatch` if you want to run Stopwatch Class(File).

[image: Screenshot of Edit Configurations tab I'm talking about]